# How to check if a Part of a Foreign Window is overlayed

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I am building a HUD for Pokerstars to show some related Statistics.

The Overlay is a UserControl : Form and i hide it from statusbar and Alt+T by winapi.
acutally it has a TopMost, to be always over the Pokertable, but this causes some Sideeffects:

i attached a screnshot to show my problem

- 1: Everything is OK
- 2: just a part of the Pokertable is overlayed by my webbrowser, in this case the HUD shows up (OK!)
- 3: The Browser overlayed the area of the Pokertable where the HUD is placed. In this case my HUD should not be TopMost;

Data i have:

- IntPtr Handle (of PokerTable)
- Point Position (on the Screen)
- Point Size (from Window)

Which WinAPI function can help ne? anyone knows some examples?
im sure, that its possible, there are Porgrams (PokerTracker, HoldemManager) which solved this Challenge.

The TopMost im using is to be always on top of the PokerTable. So if the user clicks on it, the HUD may not be overlayed.

[image: 3 Cases]

---

//edit

i did it now with a Timer on 1ms intervalls, its working 60%, has some sideffects. better as nothing

```
   if (GetForegroundWindow() == TableHandle) {
            this.TopMost = true;
        } else {
            this.TopMost = false;
        }
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out by myself - here we go!

```
public class WinAPI {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

    public const int GWL_HWNDPARENT = -8;
}


WinAPI.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, WinAPI.GWL_HWNDPARENT, (uint)this.ObservedHandle);
```